# User-defined deduction guide for lambda

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction

today I'm struggling with C++ templates. This is my simple code for convenient exception handling in JNI code.

```
template<typename T>
std::optional<T> handleNativeCrash(JNIEnv *env, std::function<T(void)> f) {
    try {
        return std::optional<T>(f());
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e) {
        jniThrowException(env, e.what());
        return {};
    }
}
```

When I try to use it without specifying `T`, Clang fails roughly with this error

```
no matching function for call to 'handleNativeCrash'
      return my_namespace::handleNativeCrash(env, [&]{
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /......../jni.cpp:116:39)'
      std::optional<T> handleNativeCrash(JNIEnv *env, std::function<T(void)> f) {
                       ^
  1 error generated.
```

I would like to infer `T` automatically from lambda return type. I tried to write deduction guide, but it seems that I'm unable to write it for global function. I tried to create simple template struct which contained only this function, but I failed too. It seems I don't really understand C++ template metaprogramming.

My first attempt was like this, but Clang just crashed complaining about illegal syntax and printing it's backtrace. I will report bug soon, but I need to finish this job first.

```
template<typename T>
handleNativeCrash(JNIEnv *env, std::function<T(void)> f) -> handleNativeCrash<decltype(f())>;
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: A lambda is not a `std::function`. Better use a generic `Callable` type.

Comment: About your clang crash: clang is right it's illegal (missing `auto`), wrong to crash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use template deduction for that, it's not smart enough and only works on matching.

But you can manually infer it:

```
template<class Callable>
auto handleNativeCrash(JNIEnv *env, Callable f)
-> std::optional<decltype(f())>
{
    try {
        return f();
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e) {
        jniThrowException(env, e.what());
        return {};
    }
}
```

[Simplified live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f4cf871345d3d3c)

Comment: Why not use automatic return-type-deduction? Do you actually want to use SFINAE?

Comment: @dedup that's an option but basically I didn't want to hide the return type (an noptional) inside the function impl.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a lambda can be converted to a `std::function` but isn't a `std::function`.

So the `T` type can't be deduced because you don't have a `std::function` and a `std::function` can't be obtained because you don't know `T`.

A sort of chicken and egg problem.

So you have to pass a `std::function` to `handleNativeCrash()`

```
return my_namespace::handleNativeCrash(env, std::function{[&]{/*...*/}});
```

or you have to receive a generic callable as in YSC answer or, by example, something as follows (thanks to Holt for pointing my original error):

```
template <typename R = void, typename F,
          typename T = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<void, R>,
                          decltype(std::declval<F>()()), R>>
std::optional<T> handleNativeCrash(JNIEnv *env, F f) {
    try {
        return std::optional<T>(f());
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e) {
        jniThrowException(env, e.what());
        return {};
    }
}
```

The YSC solution (detecting returned type using `decltype()` in trailing return type) impose the type returned by the functional; using additionals (with default values) template parameters permit also to "hijack" the returned type explicating it.

Suppose you have a `l` lambda that return an `int` but you want a `std::optional<long>`, you can write something as

```
return my_namespace::handleNativeCrash<long>(env, l);
```

Comment: You cannot put `T` before `F` since the default value for `T` depends on `F` so you cannot specify only `long` in  your last example.

Comment: @Holt - D'oh! You're right. I have to make it a little more complicated. Corrected; thanks.